# How the DEL Key with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, mozilla, keycode

I need the help for my problem in my asp.net MVC3 application I have a textbox which is validating for currency format ($228.00) but in this text box it doesn't work for the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key because <kbd>.</kbd> and delete key have same ASCII key which 46. I also set a validation in this textbox for <kbd>.</kbd> is only one time will be accept in the text box so if "." entered one time then delete will not work.

Here is my validate Javascript:

```
function validateForCharacter(val, id, e) {
    window.event.keyCode : -1;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode || e.which;
    var currentChar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (val.indexOf(currentChar) != -1 && currentChar == ".")
    {
           return false;
    }
    if (key >= 48 && key <= 57 || key == 46 || e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 9 || e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 35 || e.keyCode === 39)
    {
           $(this).val("");
           return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

This is my View (Html) code for textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" onkeypress="return validateForCharacter(value, id, event)/>
```

Comment: `"." and delete key have same ASCII key` ? really?

Comment: `window.event.keyCode : -1;` ?

Comment: yes when i print the "." and delete key by e.keyCode, e.charCode, e.which in firefox then print in 46... really...

Comment: The KeyCodes must be different! But the KeyCode of `DEL` equals the ASCII-Code of `.` see [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery does it right... but in case you need specifically detect delete key on Firefox or IE9 you can use `event.key` property.

I.E:

```
if (event.key == "Delete")
```

Live Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nondeletable").on("keydown", function(event) {
    $("#result").html(event.type + ": " + event.which);
    if (event.key == "Delete")
      $("#result").append(" <b>Delete!</b>");
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nondeletable" />
<div id="result"></div>
```